# Recommending optimal values for a process based on Time-Series data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, python, k-nearest-neighbour

I have an industrial process having **5 attributes** *(assume 1 gauges and 4 knobs)*. The process is driven by controlling the 4 knobs and the gauge tells us the performance. Now, the gauge's range is **[-1000,1000]** and it's optimal range is **[2,3]**.

I want to design a system which recommends optimal settings for the **4 knobs** resulting an optimal value for the gauge.

#### Data

I have Time-Series data having continuous values. Total features = 5 (all continuous). Data dimensions = (70000, 5). NOTE: It's time-series so the index is time_stamp.

#### So far:

Based on basic research. I implemented a K-NN variation - recommended values of 4 knob variables by finding the records in the data that are closest to the values 1 gauge variable.

```
GetClosest(DATA, OPTIMAL_VALUE):
    closestIndex = index of the record in DATA where gauge value of that record is similar to optimal gauge value i.e. OPTIMAL_VALUE
    closestRecord = DATA[closestIndex]
    return closestRecord

data = [[K1, K2, K3, K4, G1], [K1, K2, K3, K4, G1], ....]
OPTIMAL_VALUE = 2.1 # it is in the range **[2,3]**

result = GetClosest(data, OPTIMAL_VALUE)
print "Set following values to get **2.1** in Gauge\n", result[K1, K2, K3, K4]
```

This works fine. As it should. No machine learning involved. Simple Calculation.

Problem with this is inherited from k-NN. Data requires to be loaded into the memory, which is not a good practice, esp. if the data is too much (I believe).

#### Questions:

1. Does the above formulation of the problem seems reasonable?
2. Is kNN actually applicable to this kind of problems? Is this
   considered recommendation model (in ML perspective)?
3. I tried treating it as a forecasting problem, and implemented an
   LSTM (described [HERE](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/)). But, it didn't give quite inaccurate
   results. Should this be treated as a forecasting problem?
4. Is there any other technique/algorithm, I should look into?

Please pardon any mistakes (BUT, do point out). Still learning.